# UILabel Value .56 Make it 56%

Tags: uilabel, uislider

I have a label that is controlled for a UISlider. When I get half way with the slider it shows .50. How can I change that .50 to 50%? Thanks so much!

My slider code:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    tipPercentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.2f", [sender value]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UISlider is a fraction between 0.0 and 1.0.

So how about something like:

```
tipPercentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %f%%", ([sender value] * 100)];
```

The "`%%`" in the format string indicates a percent character to be printed.  I might be a tiny bit off in the format string (maybe cast the multiplied value to an integer and use "`%d%%`").